# Store function with different arguments into map

Tags: c++, function, lambda, std

I need to call a lot of functions with different arguments, depending on current state. State is stored into map with function as a value. Here is what I came to. It works, but I believe there is more elegant way to do it.

```
QMap<int, std::function<void(int, int, int, QString)>> map;

void run(){
    populateMap();
    auto f = map.value(0);
    f(1,2,3, "str3");
    auto fb = map.value(1);
    fb(1,2,3, "str3");
}
void show(){
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO;
}

void showB(int A, int B, QString str){
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"A"<<A<<B<<str;
}

void populateMap(){
    std::function<void(int, int, int, QString)>fshow = [=](int a, int b, int c, QString str) -> void{
        this->show();
    };
    std::function<void(int, int, int, QString)>fshowB = [=](int a, int b, int c, QString str) -> void{
        this->showB(a, b, str);
    };
    map.insert(0, fshow);
    map.insert(1, fshowB);
}
```

In fact, I have 5 or 6 different types of argument. Keeping every one of them and removing unused warnings afterwards is a bit of overcode. Would like to find appropriate solution.

Comment: You should elaborate on why you need this. There might be a better approach.

Comment: This screams state pattern all over the place. Check if it fits your domain. https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Comment: which part can be changed ? (I mean doing `run() {show(); showB(1, 2, "str3");}`) is probably not what you want... You might want several map, you might want a struct to group your arguments, ...

Comment: I worked with switch statements before, but since it grew to 18 and more cases, i've tried to find more readable solution.

Comment: I try to get with state patterns, but I separated the state and behavior of it into different logical classes, because it has a different behavior on different logical parts of program. Putting arguments into struct with tagged union is may be an option. But I was looking for some template solution. Storing template parameters into map is forbidden, thats where I stuck

Comment: How would you know that `map.value(0)` need no parameters whereas `map.value(1)` requires 3 ?

Comment: By current state and the function where I call value(). I’ll try to be more concrete. I have a slots, where I get replies from the net part. Net part provides connection to different slots depends on arguments. That’s where I want to call stored function. I think I’ll make a kind of basic argument struct to pass through it

Comment: Have you looked at the [Visitor Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor) - code example here: [Visitor in C++](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2).  I think you could replace your `QMap` of `std::function`s with one or more specialized Visitor entities, calling the appropriate 'show' method with variables provided by the Element entities.